# This operation is not supported in wcf test client because it uses type System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, wcf

After running WCF Service I got the Error

> This operation is not supported in wcf test client because it uses
>   type System.IO.Stream

My WCF Service code is

```
        [OperationContract]
                void getImg(Stream stream);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a list of features not supported by WCF Test Client:

1. Types: Stream, Message, XmlElement, XmlAttribute, XmlNode, types that     implement the IXmlSerializable interface, including the related XmlSchemaProviderAttribute attribute, and the XDocument and XElement types and the ADO.NET DataTable type.
2. Duplex contract.
3. Transaction.
4. Security: CardSpace , Certificate, and Username/Password.
5. Bindings: WSFederationbinding, any Context bindings and Https binding,     WebHttpbinding (Json response message support).

Source: [MSDN - WCF Test Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx#sectionToggle19)